# ValueError: time data '22.12.2012 17:00' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y %I:%M', am/pm

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime

a have a litle problem to parse a string into a datetime object in python. 
The following code working for some values but not always and a dont know whats wrong with this litel peace of code.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("22.12.2012 17:00", '%d.%m.%Y %I:%M')
```

> ValueError: time data '22.12.2012 17:00' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y %I:%M'

I think the problem clould somthing with the time and am/pm?. Because the error pops only by time > 12:00  and the string "22.12.2012 17:00" works fine.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the %H token instead of %I:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime("22.12.2012 17:00", '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
```

%I is for 12-hour date format. %H is for 24-hour date format, as explained in the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Great. Glad I could help. You might want to accept the answer if it answered your question. Cheers.